# Validating token with Azure active directory user_info and token_info end points

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an existing spring boot application which provides Rest API's and it doen't do authentication. Authentication is being handled by FrontEnd applcation and for evert API request from FrontEnd, we receive token in the Request Headers(authorization) and we validate this token by calling below 2 service provider endpoints using `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` before proceed with the API requests. For this we have written an interceptor to intercept every request and validate the token.

Token Info end point to validate token and User Info endpoint to get User Details.

```
UserInfo: https://dev-login.iam.organisation.com/organisationsso/oauth2/userinfo
TokenInfo: https://dev-login.iam.organisation.com/organisationsso/oauth2/tokeninfo?access_token=
```

**User Info Sample request:**

```
curl -X GET \
  https://dev-login.iam.organisation.com/organisationsso/oauth2/userinfo \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6Il…' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

**Token Info Sample request:**

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://dev-login.iam.organisation.com/organisationsso/oauth2/tokeninfo?access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6Il..' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'
```

Now we are changing the IAM service provider to Azure Active Directory B2C and I don't have much idea on how to validate tokeninfo and userinfo with Azure AD using existing `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` or different approach.

I have found docs for [userinfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/userinfo) and it seems we can use `RestTemplate` to call the endpoint to get the user information but could not find the Rest Template approach for Token info.

Can someone guide me to the correct and simple approach to avoid the multiple changes in the existing code.

Answer (score 1):

**ACCESS TOKENS**

For access tokens you will use JWT validation in memory - here is a [Spring Boot API Example](https://curity.io/resources/learn/spring-boot-api/).

**USER INFO**

To get user info in an API is tricky - not sure if you need to do that? If so you may need to get a different (graph) token using the `On Behalf Of Flow`.

**RESOURCES OF MINE**

I remember struggling with some of this a couple of years ago, so my links below may provide a useful hint or two:

- [Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts)
- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/01/azure-ad-spa-code-sample/)